# Scipy interp1d inversion when using an array input: how to find the root of the output function array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

Let's say I have the following 3d-Numpy-array A:

```
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 1,  4,  9]],

       [[ 1,  8, 27],
        [ 1, 16, 81]]])
```

I want to interpolate the data using `interp1d` with `axis=2`, i.e. interpolate the function values `1,2,3`, `1,4,9`, `1,8,27` and `1,16,81` with `x=np.array([1,2,3])` simultaneously (the values represent f(x)=x, x^2, x^3 and x^4, respectively).

Luckily, this is possible since interp1d is able to take ND-arrays as a second argument, as long as the interpolation axis is equal to the length of x:

```
f = interp1d(x,A,kind='linear',axis=2,fill_value='extrapolate')
```

So far this works pretty well, f(1) produces

```
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]]),
```

f(2) produces

```
array([[ 2.,  4.],
       [ 8., 16.]])
```

and the interpolation f(1.5) produces

```
array([[1.5, 2.5],
       [4.5, 8.5]])
```

i.e. I get a 2x2 array of interpolation functions f(x), evaluated at x.

Now comes the problem: I want to invert these interpolation functions to get an an x for a specific function value - element wise for each entry of the 2x2 array.

When dealing with a 1D-function g this is usually done by finding the root of the interpolation function minus the requested function value, say a:

```
g_subtracted = lambda x: f(x) - a
```

and finding the zero, for example using scipy.optimize.newton:

```
optimize.newton(g_subtracted,1.0)
```

where 1.0 is an initial guess.

Here is my actual question: **how can I find the zero of my 2x2 interp2d function array f element wise?** When I simply do

```
f_subtracted = lambda x: f(x) - a
```

(this works well for my function array) and then

```
optimize.newton(f_subtracted,1.0)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-187-4cf34581a978>", line 1, in <module>
newton(f,1.0)

File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/zeros.py", line 201, in newton
if q1 == q0:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Seems to me that optimize.newton is not able to deal with 'function arrays' as input to evaluate them element-wise. Does anyone know a way how to do it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the most general terms this is an NP hard problem, and an inverse is not generally defined. The inverse of your arbitrary function is not guaranteed to exist, even if it were 1-d instead of 4-d. For example let's say my arbitrary function was 1D and given by the table `A = [1,2,1,0]`. I can easily interpolate **from** `A` at any x, e.g., `f = interp1d([0,1,2,3],A,kind='linear')` gives `f(0.5) == 1.5`, but notice also that `f(1.5) == 1.5`. There are two `x` values for which `f(x)` equals 1.5! Therefore inverting `f` (or really `A`) is not possible over all `x`. Therefore you have to subdivide your `x` domain into regions in which the inverse exists, and somehow know from which one you would like to obtain the inverse.

Now, introduce higher dimensions on `A` and `f`, as your example does. "Subdividing x" becomes a problem of selecting n-dimensional volumes in which `A` can be inverted. You can get a sense of how this is an intractable problem for which there is no generic solution.

That being said, if you know (or assume) your `f` is invertible it is possible to construct an inverse for each dimensions of your result. So instead of `f_subtracted = lambda x: f(x) - a` you could do

```
f_subtracted00 = lambda x: f(x)[0,0] - a
f_subtracted01 = lambda x: f(x)[0,1] - a
```

etc..

Solve each individually...since the output space of `f` is Cartesian, using any component will give you the same resulting value for `x`, hence you actually **only need to solve one of the above**.

Comment: Thanks! In general you are right. Luckily, I expect strict monotonicity because its experimental data and in theory the interpolated functions should be invertible. However, experimental inaccuracies and artifacts can cause not-monotonic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `interp1d` is not really recommended. Better use a more specific interpolator. For instance, here's a cubic spline:

```
In [13]: x = [1, 2, 3]

In [14]: A = np.array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
    ...:         [ 1,  4,  9]],
    ...: 
    ...:        [[ 1,  8, 27],
    ...:         [ 1, 16, 81]]])

In [15]: from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

In [17]: spl = CubicSpline(x, A.T)   # <<<< Not the transpose: interpolation is along axis=0

In [19]: spl.roots()
Out[19]: 
array([[array([ 0.]), array([], dtype=float64)],
       [array([], dtype=float64), array([ 1.19999999,  1.20000001])]], dtype=object)

In [20]: r = spl.roots()

In [21]: r.shape
Out[21]: (2, 2)
```

However, a regular way of doing these sorts of things is an inverse interpolation: interpolate `y` vs `x`, and compute the value of interpolator at zero.
For this, you'd need to loop over the input array manually since scipy interolators do not accept n-dim `x` array.